# Programmatically undocking groups of tabbed QDockWidgets

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qdockwidget

When the GroupedDragging option is enabled for QMainWindow, is there any way to programmatically drag the dock widgets as groups out of the main window? Calling QDockWidget::setFloating(bool) just undocks the current dock widget. I can achieve this by modifying Qt, but I prefer other ways if there are any. Thanks!

Comment: Any solution you found to this? I am stuck on something that got me to your question here. I also found your QT ticket, but no answer there either.